# How to move a longtable in an enumerate?

Tags: longtable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item
\begin{longtable}[l]{|m{.1\linewidth}|m{.85\linewidth}|}\hline
a & \lipsum[1] \\\hline
  & c \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

I want to move the top of the table such that it is on the second item. Is there a simple way to do so? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to guess .95\linewidth, you can indent the table by the list's indentation and make it exactly `\linewidth` wide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item \mbox{}\\[-3\baselineskip]
{\LTleft=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep
\begin{longtable}{|m{.2\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                      m{.8\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                    |}\hline
a & \lipsum[1] \\\hline
  & c \\\hline
\end{longtable}}

\item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `\mbox{}`?

Comment: @AFeldman same reason you added `~` and Bernard and Barbara added `\leavevmode`, to force a paragraph start to trigger the item label to be inserted.  It's in general better than `~` as it has no horizontal space (although doesn't make so much difference here)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it was along those lines.  The answer is very instructive, and a great solution to the OP's problem. `\phantom{~}` would also do the same?

Comment: @AFeldman no phantom takes up as much space as the thing it is hiding (it's also considerably more code internally) (`\leavevmode` is the most efficient but `\mbox{}` is closer to official latex)

Answer (score 5):

this is a kludge.  depending on what else is on the page, the alignment
of the first line of the table might not be very good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item \leavevmode
\vspace{-1.75\baselineskip}
\begin{longtable}[l]{m{.05\linewidth}|m{.1\linewidth}|m{.8\linewidth}|}%
\cline{2-3}
 & a & \lipsum[1] \\\cline{2-3}
 &  & c \\\cline{2-3}
\end{longtable}

\item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. I replace `long table`  with `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{ltablex}
     \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \item \leavevmode\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin\relax}{|m{.1\linewidth}|X|}%[l]

    \hline
    a & \lipsum[1] \\\hline
      & c \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \item third
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The enumerated number must be outside the table.

Comment: That was unclear to me. I'll update my answer in moment.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another kludge ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum}
\setlength\LTleft{50pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\vskip2in   
\item first
\vskip.2in
\item ~
\vskip-.27in
\begin{longtable}[]{|m{.1\linewidth}|m{.85\linewidth}|}\hline
a & \lipsum[1] \\\hline
  & c \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The enumerated number must be outside the table.

Comment: Changed the answer to make the number outside the table.

Comment: Always a pleasure :)